# Add to cart urls for Wix are they similar to WooCommerce?

Tags: url, woocommerce, product, cart, velo

In WooCommerce add to cart Urls are like: `https://domainexample.com/?add-to-cart=651`

Is there an equivalent of add to cart urls for wix, like we have in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 2):

Well you have the [addToCart()](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/carticon/addtocart) API

You could use some logic on a separate page to retrieve the URL values using Wix Location's [query function](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-location/query) and add the item to the cart but this will probably take more processing time.